# Route53 is changing my Cloudfront site to "not secure"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

The entirety of my web application is contained within various AWS services and is working properly with *Cloudfront*.

When I go to `abcxxxx.cloudfront.net` my site works as expected and is secured with `https`.

When I try and use my own custom domain with *Route53* and setting `www.mywebsite.com` and `mywebsite.com` as aliases, it is no longer secure.

My alias target for each is the proper *Cloudfront* domain.

I don't know if the following has to do with my problem but when I try to go to `mywebsite.com` it says:

> "this site cannot be reached"

but when I go to `www.mywebsite.com` it redirects to `https` with the "*https*" crossed out in red and displays `"not secure"`.

*Cloudfront* also has the proper *CNAMES*.

How do I properly configure *Route53* to work like my *Cloudfront* domain?

Comment: Route53 is just a DNS service. It just resolves a hostname to an IP address. It isn't involved in negotiating HTTPS connections at all. It sounds like you need to configure CloudFront to be aware of your custom domain name, and you need to create an SSL Certificate for your custom domain name and add it to CloudFront.

Comment: Cloudfront creates a default SSL certificate for you and Cloudfront is aware of the proper CNAMES.

Comment: SSL certificates are tied to specific domain names. The SSL certificate that CloudFront provided for you is for the `cloudfront.net` domain name. You have to setup an SSL certificate for your custom domain name if you want connections to your custom domain to use SSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark B answered the question. Don't use Cloudfront's default SSL Certificate. Go to Certificate Manager and request a new one and use that one in Cloudfront. My site then worked exactly as expected

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. Spent ages messing around with this!