# How do I secure my Static website hosted by AWS S3 , Route53, CloudFront & ACM

Tags: amazon-s3, https, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, aws-acm

I have followed this guide on  [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html). I am trying to host a simple static website in the UK [eu-west-2]. I can see that a few people have asked this question but none of the solutions seem to change this status :/ The web content shows up ok but the address bar shows that the website is not secure.

From what I understand

- To be able to use Cloudfront, the SSL certificate xxxxxx.co.uk (with both [www.xxxxxx.co.uk](http://www.xxxxxx.co.uk) & xxxxxx.co.uk) must be requested in N.Virginia region, [which I created & linked from scratch incase the default was faulty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45216971/route53-is-changing-my-cloudfront-site-to-not-secure) :check
- Configure root domain bucket for website hosting & Configure  subdomain bucket for website redirect
- DNS validation for SSL certificate so that Cname records are automatically added to R53. Crossed checked to see that the correct cname is linked to the SSL certificate used by Cloudfront
- At one stage, I added the Alias to CloudFront as an A record in my R53 for xxxxxx.co.uk. It didn't work, because there was nothing pointing to the root domain bucket anymore [Thought i'd mention this incase it helps with troubleshooting]

I've checked [AWS ACM Troubleshooting advice](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/acm-certificate-error-https/) too :

- Certificate for the domain(/s) is new
- [Caches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67656456/changing-static-content-on-s3-bucket-to-domain) cleared when refreshing page / Tried a different browser
- It's a simple [www.xxxxxx.co.uk](http://www.xxxxxx.co.uk) website and so the certificate **is** valid for the name of the server

Other resource used include

- https://towardsdatascience.com/static-hosting-with-ssl-on-s3-a4b66fb7cd00
- https://medium.com/@aidan.hallett/how-to-set-up-a-static-website-with-ssl-tls-and-a-custom-domain-using-aws-s3-and-cloudfront-145be108b431

But I still get the 'Not secure' [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMiQV.png) which is driving me batty atm. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why exactly does your browser say your connection isn’t secure? Can you please share more details on that?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your time. If you click the link in the last line of my post. Stack Overflow has let me add an image which shows what I mean. Thanks again. 

"But I still get the 'Not secure' >>>error<< which is driving me batty atm. Thanks in advance"

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that. I would suggest to write this out (in more detail), and maybe emphasise that you only get this vague error. Anyway, those things are admittedly hard to debug, but let me check if I can dig up a Cloudformation template that should get you going. One more question, though: Where did you register the domain? And, if it’s not AWS, how did you configure it?

Comment: I got the domain via Route53 in AWS and followed the resources mentioned in the details section for the question. Apologies, I wouldn't know if there is more detail I could specify. When it comes to Cloudfront, I have minimal knowledge. I would prefer to create it without a template a learn from the bugs if possible, rather than using a CF template. It's only a personal project but I appreciate the offer.